# How do you assign methods to custom objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don’t know if I'm using the correct terminology here, but when I call `file.close()` with `file` being an instance of the custom object `midi` I want to execute the code

```
 import subprocess
 import os

#file is a placeholder name
 os.chdir('/Users/benjaminvakil/Desktop')
        path = str(subprocess.run(
                ['mdfind', file.filename.split(
            '.')[0] + '.txt'], capture_output=True).stdout).split(
                    '\\n')[0][2:]
        if path =='':
            path = str(subprocess.run(
                ['mdfind', file.filename.split(
            '.')[0] + '.txt'], capture_output=True).stdout).split(
                    '\\n')[0][2:]

        subprocess.run(['mv', path, file.filename], capture_output=True)
```

how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Create a new subclass that inherits from `midi` with your changes to the close() method and use that class instead of `midi`

Comment: Alternatively you can bind a new `close()` method to an existing instance of `midi` via `file.close = myclosefunction`, but I would recommend against that.

Comment: You need to provide more information. It is totally unclear what you are asking. What is your "custom object"? Do you mean some instance of a custom defined class? Do you control the definition of that class? It seems to me you need to read up on the basics of OOP in python, classes, methods etc. Start with the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)